# How to gracefully protect/exit a multi-threaded program in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, exit, free

I have a C program where I run 3 branches of code: 2 that i started through pthread_create and the normal one.
I am wondering how to correctly protect it if my second thread fails to be created somehow.
Here is my code:

```c
# include <pthread.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <semaphore.h>
# include <errno.h> 

typedef struct s_philo{
    sem_t       *first;
    sem_t       *second;
    sem_t       *stop_A;
    sem_t       *stop_B;
    pthread_t   A_thread;
    pthread_t   B_thread;
}   t_philo;

void    sem_close_safe(sem_t    *sem)
{
    if (sem_close(sem) == -1)
        printf("Failed to close semaphore\n");
}

int    free_philo(t_philo *philo)
{
    if (philo->first)
        sem_close_safe(philo->first);
    if (philo->second)
        sem_close_safe(philo->second);
    if (philo->stop_A)
        sem_close_safe(philo->stop_A);
    if (philo->stop_B)
        sem_close_safe(philo->stop_B);
    free(philo);
    return (1);
}

void    *check_philo(t_philo *philo)
{
    void    *check;

    check = philo;
    if (!philo->first || !philo->second || !philo->stop_A || !philo->stop_B)
        check = NULL;
    return (check);
}

sem_t   *sem_open_new_safe(const char *name, unsigned int value)
{
    sem_t   *sem;

    sem = sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, value);
    if (errno == EEXIST)
    {
        if (sem_unlink(name) == -1)
            return (NULL);
        sem = sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, value);
    }
    if (sem == SEM_FAILED)
        return (NULL);
    if (sem_unlink(name) == -1)
    {
        sem_close_safe(sem);
        return (NULL);
    }
    return (sem);
}

void    *A(void *p)
{
    t_philo *philo;

    philo = (t_philo *) p;

    sem_wait(philo->stop_A);
    sem_post(philo->stop_A);
    return (NULL);
}

void    *B(void *p)
{
    t_philo *philo;

    philo = (t_philo *) p;

    sem_wait(philo->stop_B);
    sem_post(philo->stop_B);
    return (NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    t_philo *philo;
    int i;

    philo = malloc(sizeof(*philo));
    philo->first = sem_open_new_safe("/first", 1);
    philo->second = sem_open_new_safe("/second", 1);
    philo->stop_A = sem_open_new_safe("/stop_A", 0);
    philo->stop_B = sem_open_new_safe("/stop_B", 0);
    if (!check_philo(philo))
        return (free_philo(philo));
    if (pthread_create(&philo->A_thread, NULL, &A, (void *)philo))
        return (free_philo(philo));
    if (pthread_create(&philo->B_thread, NULL, &B, (void *)philo))
        return (free_philo(philo));
    i = 0;
    while (i++ < 100)
    {
        if (sem_wait(philo->first) == -1)
            sem_post(philo->stop_B);
        if (sem_wait(philo->second) == -1)
            sem_post(philo->stop_A);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        sem_post(philo->second);
        sem_post(philo->first);
    }
    sem_post(philo->stop_B);
    sem_post(philo->stop_A);
    pthread_join(philo->A_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(philo->B_thread, NULL);
    free_philo(philo);
    return (0);
}
```

Both of my A and B threads wait for semaphores on their first lines of code so they will never return on their own if I do not post these semaphores.

Should I pthread_join thread A ? Should I manually post some semaphores to force thread A to continue its execution and return ? Or maybe I should use pthread_detach ? I am a bit lost.

Edit: I have been asked to post more code to make it executable, but I have a lot of lines of code and it would just drown the above one. What I am looking for (if it exists) is not a guided code-specific answer, but more of a best practice to gracefully handle pthread_create errors.

Edit 2: I added the least code I could to make it runnable

Comment: `struct` [is a keyword in C](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.1) so the posted code should not compile, and `memset(struct);` is just plain wrong.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: What do you mean by `memset(philo);` ?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: My code is more than 1000 lines so I cannot post everything... I added the code-structures of my threads and my philo structure. Is my question code-dependant ? Are there no best practice of doing this ?

Comment: memset(philo) just inits my philo structure to zeros everywhere, this line could be removed actually since I modified my philo structure for the example.

Comment: The arguments to `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` should be pointers to `sem_t`, not semaphore names.  The names are used only when creating a named semaphore or opening an existing one.

Comment: I think the code is actually a red herring - neither complete, nor an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), nor really pseudocode.

Comment: And unless you want multiple runs of your program, especially multiple *concurrent* runs, to use the same semaphores, you should probably be using anonymous ones, not named ones.

Comment: Okay, the code above is finally runnable. About the named semaphores, my whole program runs multiple processes that need to use shared semaphores so I think I need them, right ?

Comment: Failing to create a thread is a fatal error.  The process is in a bad shape, typically out of system resources like handles or address space.  No point in trying to continue, it will just die soon after, display or log the error return value and terminate quickly with _exit().

Comment: ...what Hans says.  Just exit/abort/terminateProcess before anything gets any worse.  Threads do not 'fail to create' unless you screwed up.  Remove the screwup instead of trying to apply band-aid to a brute-force trauma:)

Comment: 'my whole program runs multiple processes' do you have to do that?  Multiple process systems are a major PITA for shutdown management. Threads are much easier:)

Comment: I didn't know failing to create a thread was such a serious issue. Is it as serious if a write call fails for example ? Or a gettimeofday call, a sem_open call, etc fails ? This assignment is for school and it is mandatory to use processes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general case looks something like this pseudocode:

```
if (!setup_A()) {
  exit(FAILURE);
}
if (!setup_B()) {
  teardown_A();
  exit(FAILURE);
}
if (!setup_C()) {
  teardown_B();
  teardown_A();
  exit(FAILURE);
}

do_successful_processing();

teardown_C();
teardown_B();
teardown_A();
```

and you're effectively asking how to write `teardown_B()`.

The general *solution* (assuming you can't just switch to C++ to use proper destructors and RAII) does not exist. The teardown is just as specific to the details of A, B, C and your application as the setup is.

---

> I am wondering how to correctly protect it if my second thread fails to be created somehow.

The proximate answer is to tell the thread to quit (in some application-specific way), and then to join it.

The actual semantics of requesting a shutdown are specific to your code, since you wrote the function that thread is executing. Here, it should be sufficient to `sem_post` the semaphone thread `A` is waiting on.

NB. **DO NOT** use `pthread_kill` to shut down threads, if you can possibly avoid it. It's much better to write clean shutdown handling explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for. You make me wonder, in bigger programs that may run hundreds of different threads, is it handled this way ? Do they code some kind of exit_thread_error function ?

Comment: If there are lots of threads, they're typically arranged in pools and a pool will have some kind of standard task queue mechanism. You expect the pool to have some kind of shutdown method which will tell each thread to exit (using the queue) before joining them.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering how to correctly protect it if my second thread fails to be created somehow.

Easiest would be to simply call `exit(1)` in the case that thread creation fails.  That will terminate the whole process, including all its threads.  All resources owned by the process will be cleaned up by the system.

That does create a possible issue if the program wants to clean up any *persistent* resources, such as files or named semaphores.  Often that's not a major issue, for if the program fails then it may be ok for its termination to be less tidy than if it succeeds.  Nevertheless, there are ways to reduce that impact.

In particular, you can minimize the program's use of modifiable persistent resources.  For example, your program would be all-around cleaner if it used *unnamed* semaphores instead of named ones.  You would not need to watch out for existing ones when you create them, and since they are being used only within a single process, you would not need to worry about failing to clean them up before terminating.

But where you want some kind of affirmative cleanup to happen when the program terminates, you always have the option to use [`atexit()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) to register an exit handler to perform that.  There are some caveats, but it's good to be aware of this option.

> Should I pthread_join thread A ?

In your particular example, I see no reason to do so.  It might be more appropriate in other cases.

> Should I manually post some semaphores to force thread A to continue its execution and return ?

If you plan to join thread A then you need to ensure that it will, in fact, terminate.  In this case, it looks like yes, you could achieve that by semaphore manipulation, but cases where it actually mattered would be more complex.  Ensuring A's timely would probably not be so simple in such cases.

> Or maybe I should use pthread_detach ?

There is no advantage at all to doing that in this case.  Thread A will be terminated when the process terminates, regardless of whether it is detached.  And presumably that's what you want in your example, for it would not make progress if it were the only live thread left in the process.

Comment: I will modify my semaphores to name only the ones that I need to share between several processes. This answer was very enlightning, thank you

Comment: If I did not post my semaphores stop_A and stop_B at the end of my main, threads A and B would not terminate. What should I do in that situation ?

Comment: @renaldo_kurifu, the *whole process* terminates when any thread calls `exit()` or when the initial thread returns from the initial call to `main()`.  That means all threads.  Your threads A and B will not survive such an event, no matter what they are doing.  And they will not prevent the process termination from completing.

Comment: would'nt I get stuck on the pthread_join lines ? And by "what should I do", I meant how to exit them in a nice way. Do I mandatory need to sem_post to make them continue their run or is it okay to just free everything and exit the initial thread ? And if I free everything, won't I have a problem on my sem_wait lines as my threads would be  trying to access already free'd resources ? @John

Comment: @renaldo_kurifu, you will not get stuck on `pthread_join()` if you do not *call* `pthread_join()`.  That there is no universal need to do so is the main thesis of this answer.  You can call `exit()` or perform a `return` from `main` *without*, and in many cases that's the cleanest and easiest thing to do in a failure case.  All non-persistent resources -- allocated memory, no-longer-referenced unnamed semaphores, and more -- will be released automatically by the system.

Comment: You need `pthread_join()` to ensure that a thread completes its work, but often that's just what you *don't* want to do when performing an abrupt termination.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly clear. Thing is this project is for school so I need to avoid any form of valgrind leaks, even still reachable ones. I read things about this and I am aware that the program will perfectly free its resources in your solution. But valgrind gives me still reachables because of the semaphores that were not closed I guess. All in all, I think I will create a variable that I set to some value to make a thread exit, and protect it with another semaphore to avoid data races (I cannot use mutexes because of the assignment rules).

Comment: @renaldo_kurifu, refer to HansPassant's comment on the question.  If your program fails to start the second thread then it's *already* hosed.  This is not a situation that arises with a correct program running in an operating environment with enough resources to support it, unless in a situation so far out of your control that there's no way to guarantee anything. You will spend your effort where you think best, but if it were me, I would focus my effort elsewhere.